# Add style to every element child using loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got a little tab setup in my html. Like so:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab_div_1">Tab link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_div_2">Tab link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_div_3">Tab link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_div_4">Tab link 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab_content">
    <div id="tab_div_1">Tab content 1</div>
    <div id="tab_div_2">Tab content 2</div>
    <div id="tab_div_3">Tab content 3</div>
    <div id="tab_div_4">Tab content 4</div>
</div>
```

So obviously every "Tab link" opens a specific "Tab content div".

Now,...
... I want to get `position(top)` of every `ul#tabs a` and make it `padding-top` to a belonging `#tab_div`.

I can do it by doing this:

```
var tabLink = $( "a[href='#tab_div_1']" );
var position = tabLink.position();  
var tabTarget = $("#tab_div_1");

tabTarget.css("padding-top",position.top );
```

by repeating it for every tab.

But I would like to do it with a **loop** either using vanila javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#tabs').find('a').each(function(i, el){
    var $el = $(el);
    var position = $el.position();
    var target = $el.attr('href');
    $(target).css('padding-top', position.top);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! Would like to see it done using Vanilla JS though. Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can add to every tab a class and then use the vanilla JS `getElementsByClassName()`.
You'll get an array-like of the required elements which you'll be able to loop throgh.